# bulk transfer data from Oracle to postgreSQL

Tags: oracle, postgresql-12

I have an instance of Oracle on PROD VPC (in AWS) and a postgreSQL on DEV VPC (in AWS). I want to copy all tables from Oracle to postgreSQL. As they are on different VPC, I am currently using the below process:

1. Using data pump, export the tables from Oracle PROD and import them to Oracle DEV (on DEV VPC)
2. Use python to extract data from Oracle DEV in CSV format and load them to postgreSQL using COPY

Is there any other efficient way to do this copy? I am trying to copy all work schemas (DDL and data) from source to destination.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about using a foreign data wrapper from Postgres to Oracle?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, the PROD Oracle can't be accessed from DEV postgreSQL. That's why I am using step 1 to copy data from PROD Oracle to DEV Oracle. Are you saying that instead of using python in step 2, I should use FDW?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use VPC peering to get rid of the copy.[What is VPC peering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/what-is-vpc-peering.html)

Next, the oracle foreign data wrapper is a marvel to use for this kind of work. It makes your oracle tables accessible from the postgres database and makes copying data a piece of cake. A nice little python script can always help if there are many tables to handle.

Comment: VPC peering worked for me. FDW somehow was slow. So, dropped that option. Thank you.

Comment: Nice to hear something works. It would be good to know why fdw was slow for you. It should be fast.